# Backbone: Collection not rendered in View even though it's fetched

Tags: javascript, html, json, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I know that there are a few questions around regarding this, but the answers are not very clear for me to implement. That's why I'm asking this question again so I can have a clear and simple answer.

I've always had trouble with `Collection` in Backbone, especially populating it with JSON data.

I can't seem to get the collection to render in the View, even though in firebug I can see that, it's being fetched from the server, but the screen is still empty.
Also, when I do a `console.log('callers: ', this.callerList)`, it returns an object with `models=[0]`. But when I expand the object, `models` is full of data from the JSON file. What's going on with Backbone and it's confusing results?

Can someone please explain to me how to do it? I've been battling this for ages and I can't get my head around it.

Many Thanks

JS:

```
(function($, window) {

  // model
  var CallerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  // collection
  var CallersList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: CallerModel,
      url: 'js/json/callers.json'
  });

  // view
  var CallerView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '.caller-app',

      template: _.template($('#callers-template').html()),

      initialize: function() {
          this.callerList = new CallersList();
          this.callerList.fetch();
          this.callerList.bind('reset', this.render);

          console.log('caller: ', this.callerList);
      },

      render: function(e) {

                  console.log('RENDER');

          _.each(this.collection.models, function(caller) {
              this.$el.append(this.template(caller.toJSON()));
                          console.log('callerList: ', caller);
          }, this);

          return this;
      }
  });

  // start
  var callerView = new CallerView();

}(jQuery, window));
```

HTML:

```
<!-- wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Missed Calls App</h1>

    <div class="caller-app"></div>

</div>
<!-- wrapper -->


<!-- templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="callers-template">
    <div class="caller">
        <h2><%= title %> <%= name %> called</h2>
        <h3>From <%= agency %></h3>
        <p>When: <%= when %></p>
        <p>Contact: <%= tel %></p>
        <p>Says:"<%= message %>"</p>
    </div>
</script>
<!-- templates -->
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Mrs",
      "name": "Mui",
      "agency": "Ryuzanpaku Dojo",
      "when": "evening",
      "tel": "0207 123 45 67",
      "message": "Check your availability"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Mrs",
      "name": "Shigure",
      "agency": "Ryuzanpaku Dojo",
      "when": "evening",
      "tel": "0207 123 45 67",
      "message": "Check your availability"
  }
]
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems.  I would advise you to put a breakpoint at point `this.$el.append(this.template(caller.toJSON()));`.  Check that caller is correct and that caller.toJSON() returns what you think it should.  Verify that this.template is correct, $el is correct, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Neil for responding. I've just added some `console.log` in the render function to see what is inside `caller` but it seems like `render` is not even being applied.

Comment: Your trying to iterate through the collection but you haven't actually assigned it, in addition you are using this.model instead of this.collection.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. I've just updated my answer with your suggestion. But it's still not rendering anything and the render function is being called. I think the problem is deeper than that, and I can't figure out what it is. Also what do you mean by collection is not assigned?

Comment: I posted an answer with a link to a jsbin, note that I'm adding the data manually and calling the render function instead of fetching it, but it should work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actaully assigned a collection to your *CallerView*, in addition when you iterate though the collection you should be using `this.collection.models` instead of `this.model.models`

For example when initializing you caller list
        initialize: function() {

```
    initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new CallersList();
    this.collection.fetch();
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
   }
```

And when rendering

```
render: function(e) {

          _.each(this.collection.models, function(caller) {
              this.$el.append(this.template(caller.toJSON()));

          }, this);

          return this;
      }
```

Here's a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kanejubi/5/edit)

**Some additional points**

In general you want to decouple your code as much as possible. To this end it is probably better to declare and initialize your collection outside of your view and then pass it in. This also has the advantage of making your code more reusable, for example say you wanted to render a second list of calls (let say recent calls), you can now just create a second instance of your view passing in a collection and element.

For example

```
var missedCalls = new CallersList();
var callerView = new CallerView({collection : missedCalls, el: '#missedCalls' });
missedCalls.fetch();


var recentCalls = new CallerList(); //you probably want to use a different url
var recentCallersView = new CallerView({collection : recentCalls, el:'#recentCalls'}); 
recentCalls.fetch();
```

Another point worth mentioning, currently you are rendering all items in your collection for each fetch, including any that have been already rendered. You might want either empty your `el` before rendering or listen to the `add` event instead and render each item individually as it's added. In addition it's worth pointing out that  `fetch` isn't really meant to be used to load data on page load, from the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)

> Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page
>   load — all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped
>   in to place. fetch is intended for lazily-loading models for
>   interfaces that are not needed immediately: for example, documents
>   with collections of notes that may be toggled open and closed.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. I'm still confused though. What do you mean by assigning collection to the `View`? Also this doesn't explain why the JSON data is not displayed on the screen. I know about inserting data manually but this time, I want data from the server to be displayed, as that's what is used in the real world. Now I've added the `this.render()` in `initiliaze` with data from JSON but it's still working... :(

Comment: The reason I assigned the data manually was only because it was easier to set up in the jsbin, it should work the same when you fetch the data. As for assigning the collection to the view, a backbone [view](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) has a *model* property and a *collection* property (neither are required, but if you are using your view for a model then you would use the `model` property and for a collection the `collection` property.

Comment: OK, I've tried your jsbin example and it works, i.e. manual data, assigning to View like this: `var callerView = new CallerView({ collection: new CallersList });`. But as soon as I change the manual data to the server one, nothing is displayed anymore. So I think I'm not doing something right in my code when it comes to data from JSON??? There's something I must do before applying data from JSON, whether it's server or browser configuration, missing piece of code in Backbone, etc. And that's what I wanna know, how to do it right.

Comment: Apparently the newer version of backbone.js no longer reset the collection when you do a fetch unless you pass in `reset:true` to your [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch).

Comment: @Shaoz I've updated the jsBin to retrieve the data through the collections fetch.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jack, it works now. OK, 1 more question (sorry about this). When do I know that when I start my app at the end of my code, I have to do this `var callerView = new CallerView({ model: new CallerModel });` or `var callerView = new CallerView({ collection: new CallersList });`, and when do I know, I have to do just `var callerView = new CallerView();`? This assignment of model/collection is also where I get confused...

Comment: It depends on your specific app, but in general you probably want to declare it outside of your view and pass it in. I've edited my answer to include some more information regarding this.